# InteliiJ Idea doesnt download maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Today i receive notification about InteliiJ Idea's update and decided to do it. However i was using trial version of the Ultimate edition and decided to switch to community

Uninstalled ultimate version (performed OS restart), deleted all cache/profile/m2 old files and installed community version. Imported my old project, added Framework support to maven and did "Reimport".

None of the dependencies is being downloaded. Wheneever i try to add new dependency the text becomes red.

I tried everything reimport, clean, mvn clean, mvn install, even did a reinstalled the program and still my dependencies are not being downloaded.
Auto-import is on and pom. is not in the ignored list.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you've restarted intellij a few times as well? Usually when you restart there is a popup on the top right corner that asks if you should import. Is that there?

Comment: Restarted many times, no popup, nothing

Comment: just for the purpose of troubleshooting your maven installation.. On the command line from the root of your project, Does mvn clean and mvn package have any effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete everything but the .java files i wrote. Restarted the project then added framework support and now everything is fine